# Implement star rating in ASP .NET MVC with ul and li

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm wondering how do I implement a star rating system in ASP .NET MVC when the stars are encapsulated in a Ul, li.

I'm using https://htmlstream.com/preview/unify-v2.5.1/e-commerce/page-single-product-2.html as a layout.

The code below is within my form post method

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Drink", FormMethod.Post))
{
....
<!-- Rating -->
<div class="col-5 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <h3 class="h6 mb-1">Rate:</h3>
    <ul class="js-rating u-rating-v1 g-font-size-20 g-color-gray-light-v3 mb-0" data-hover-classes="g-color-primary">
        <li class="g-color-primary g-line-height-1_4 click">
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        </li>
        <li class="g-color-primary g-line-height-1_4 click">
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        </li>
        <li class="g-color-primary g-line-height-1_4 click">
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        </li>
        <li class="g-color-primary g-line-height-1_4 click">
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        </li>
        <li class="g-line-height-1_4">
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- End Rating -->
</div>
....
}
```

I'm wondering how do I let my controller know what the selected rating is?

Comment: Your form does not have any form controls so nothing would be posted to the server. You would need a hidden input for the rating and use javascript to set its value based on the selected 'star'. But it might be aesier to use a jQuery plugin that does it for you.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks, the hidden input worked with some javascript triggers!